# Condition for one section applying to all sections

Tags: python, python-2.5

I've tried fixing this multiple times, yet I still can't find out what is wrong with it. The idea is to give each "user" a different "passcode" that will either let them access something else that I will build in or end the program if its the wrong password.

However, whenever I try to assign a user a password different from that of the top user (as in the case below) it still thinks that User 1's PW is that of every other user.

So what is causing this, and how would I fix it?

```
print "Enter your name."

answer = raw_input()

if answer == "User 1":
    print "Hello.Please enter your passcode."

    answer = raw_input()

    if answer == "orion":
        print "Login request accepted. Welcome to The Database."
    elif answer != "orion":
        print "LOGIN DENIED. Your intrusion has been reported to the authorities."

elif answer == "User 2":
    print "Hello.Please enter your passcode."

    answer = raw_input()

    if answer == "bandit":
        print "Login request accepted. Welcome to The Database."
    elif answer != "bandit":
        print "LOGIN DENIED. Your intrusion has been reported to the authorities."
```

Comment: I tested it myself, there is nothing wrong with the passwords. Perhaps I don't understand your question.

Comment: As an aside, a simple `else` will suffice, instead of `elif answer != "whatever"`.

Comment: Maybe it was a problem with your indentation that got fixed by the edit? Because it works for me too.

Comment: Note that this code shows a classic problem in that you are repeating yourself without need - try looking up a python's `dict` class - a dictionary of `username: password` would be appropriate here.

Comment: Well, without testing it's easy to see that the passwords are hard coded and different in each block.  Which block that gets ran is based on the user name entered, so the password that is checked against depends entirely on which user name was entered. `{'User 1': 'orion', 'User 2': 'bandit'}`

Answer (score 1):

## Two Examples

I give you two examples on how this can be done (it is New Year's Day after all) :)

### Procedural Code

Your code works, but you may want to try this, a bit cleaner:

```
users = {"User 1" : { 'pwd' : 'bandit', 'role': 'admin'},
         "User 2" : { 'pwd' : 'orion', 'role': 'user'},
         "User 3" : { 'pwd' : 'solar', 'role': 'approver'},
         "User 4" : { 'pwd' : 'mars', 'role': 'editor'}
         }

print "Enter your name."
answer = raw_input()

INTRUSION = True

if answer in users:
    print "Hello %s. Please enter your passcode." % answer
    password = raw_input()
    if password == users[answer]['pwd']:
        INTRUSION = False

if INTRUSION:
    print "LOGIN DENIED. Your intrusion has been reported to the authorities."
else:
    print "Login request accepted. Welcome to The Database."
    print "Your role is %s." % users[answer]['role']
    # ...you can now go on to do other stuff
```

It allows you to refer to a dictionary of users and assign them different roles. You may find it easier to expand on this version.

### Object-Oriented Example

A more extended example uses a more object-oriented approach:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import hashlib

# ---------------------------- SETUP 

# data structure for holding user record in named fields
User = namedtuple('User', ['uid', 'pwd', 'role'])

# utility function to hash passwords and ensure they are
# stored in encrypted form
def hashed(s):
    return hashlib.md5(s).hexdigest()

# Class to hold the user database
# Methods could be added here e.g. add and delete users
class UserBase(object):
    def __init__(self, users={}):
        self.database = {}
        for user in users:
            self.database[user.uid] = user

    def get_user(self, uid):
        return self.database.get(uid)

# These should be stored in a database with
# hashed passwords...
users = [User("User 1", hashed('bandit'), 'admin'),
         User("User 2", hashed('orion'), 'user'),
         User("User 3", hashed('solar'), 'approver'),
         User("User 4", hashed('mars'), 'editor')]

# Instantiate the database
USERS = UserBase(users)

# ---------------------------- SETUP ENDED

# Simulate a login session

INTRUSION = True
uid = raw_input("Enter your name: ")

user = USERS.get_user(uid)
if user:
    prompt = "Hello %s. Please enter your passcode: " % user.uid
    password = raw_input(prompt)
    if hashed(password) == user.pwd:
        INTRUSION = False

if INTRUSION:
    print "LOGIN DENIED. Your intrusion has been reported to the authorities."
else:
    print "%s logged in. Welcome to The Database." % user.uid
    print "Your role is %s." % user.role
    # ...you can now go on to do other stuff
    # there is an object called user that has
    # three attributes: uid, pwd, and role
```

Comment: You could also achieve the same behavior with a class approach

Comment: You're right. This does work. But the extended version, with the code for other stuff in between these lines, doesn't for some reason. I checked the indentations, and I just don't know whats going on! The passwords are hardcoded in, but no matter what name I type it only accepts the User 1 password.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? Both your and my code are able to check the credentials of users. I am not sure what you mean by the "extended version with code for other stuff".

Comment: On a side note - I would get rid of the `print`, and put the 'prompt' as the first param to `raw_input`

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. Done, and added hashing of passwords for obsessive good measure... Afraid this might be overkill.